# Mouseover is not changing color

Tags: javascript, html, css

my HTML is:

```
<p id="demo">This is a test</p>

<script src="change_color.js"></script>
```

My JavaScript is:

```
function change_color() {
    if (test_text.style.color = 'black') {
        test_text.style.color = 'blue';
    }
    else { 
        test_text.style.color = 'yellow';
    }
}

var test_text = document.getElementById("demo");
test_text.style.color = 'black'
test_text.addEventListener("mouseover", change_color, false);
test_text.addEventListener("mouseout", change_color, false);
```

Now, why does this script change the color of the paragraph only on mouseover. and not on mouseout (it stays blue)?

Also, would it be possible to use a CSS selector inside a javascript function to set color, something like:

```
function change_color() {
    #demo {
        color = 'yellow'
}
```

Comment: Use `==` or `===` for comparison. Also, don't use Presentation (CSS) for Data (JS comparison). Instead use something like an "isToggled" boolean and set the value according to that. Also, just ditch the JS and use CSS `:hover` instead.

Comment: `if (test_text.style.color = 'black') {` this is an assignment, use `===`. And no, you can't use CSS inside a method like that

Comment: would it not be easier to simply use CSS `#demo:hover { color: yellow }` ?

Comment: Exactly. Why you want to use JS for something it's meant to be handled by CSS?!

Comment: BTW use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mistake with a comparison. You need to use `===` instead `=` *(it is assignment)*
So your function should looks like:

```js
function change_color() {
    if (test_text.style.color === 'black') {
        test_text.style.color = 'blue';
    }
    else { 
        test_text.style.color = 'yellow';
    }
}
```

Also you can't use CSS inside JS method. You can get element by using `document.querySelector("div")` or `document.getElementById("demo")` for example as you did in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing `test_text.style.color = 'black'` in your if statement, which sets the color to black instead of checking if it is

```js
function change_color() {
    if (test_text.style.color === 'black') {
        test_text.style.color = 'blue';
    }
    else { 
        test_text.style.color = 'yellow';
    }
}

var test_text = document.getElementById("demo");
test_text.style.color = 'black'
test_text.addEventListener("mouseover", change_color, false);
test_text.addEventListener("mouseout", change_color, false);
```

```html
<p id="demo">This is a test</p>

<script src="change_color.js"></script>
```

However, you can achieve the same thing with css hover:

```css
#demo {
  color: black;
}
#demo:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">This is a test</p>

<script src="change_color.js"></script>
```